# rmd file not knitting in R Studio: 'CreateProcess' failed to run'

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to knit an Rmd file in R Studio on a Windows 7 box.  Honestly, at this point, I'm just trying to get the *default* Rmd file to knit.

Whether I try to output to html or pdf, I get the following error:

> Error in system(paste(shQuote(pandoc_path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) :
>    'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\PROGRA~1\RStudio\bin\pandoc\pandoc.exe --version'
>   Calls:  ... get_pandoc_version -> with_pandoc_safe_environment -> force -> system
>   Execution halted

The same error results whether I use the nice UI "knit" button or a direct `render()` command.

Fearing that I was out of date, I have uninstalled and reinstalled both R and RStudio, so they're now at R version 3.3.2 and RStudio version 1.0.136.  The first time I created an Rmd file after the reinstallation, it asked about installing updated version of various packages.  Did that without incident, but it didn't resolve the problem.

I've tried to explicitly load the library, which informs me that there is no such package.  If I try to install the package, I get the following message:

> Warning in install.packages :
>    package ‘pandoc’ is not available (for R version 3.3.2)

The instructor pointed me to [Cannot launch pandoc in rstudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487805/cannot-launch-pandoc-in-rstudio).  (Nothing about the package not being available, so maybe that isn't important?)  Following those instructions, I've checked for a duplicate `pandoc` installation (both manually checking Userdata/Apps/local and a search for "pandoc" anywhere on the computer).  The only `pandoc` is in the RStudio bin, so I don't think that's the issue.

I have also tried the two suggestions included in [Knitr pandoc Execution halted in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886887/knitr-pandoc-execution-halted-in-r) -- namely installing MiKTeX, then installing/loading pandoc manually as outlined (along with ensuring full control permissions).  Neither fixed the problem.  (Of course, when I loaded pandoc manually, it created a duplicative `pandoc` in the system.  I therefore uninstalled that.)

Any ideas???

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the R-Studio menus try going to `Tools - Global Options... - Sweave` and changing the `Weave Rnw files using:` dropbox from `sweave` to `knitr`.

Failing that it could be that MikTeX is not linked to R. Make sure you have administrator privileges then from the start menu go to `all programs - MikTeX X.X - Maintenance - MikTeX Settings`

Click on the `Roots` tab and then select `Add...`, you then need to route to the `textmf` folder which will vary depending on where you have **R** installed, however it should be something like `C:\R\R-3.X.X\share\texmf`.

Comment: Thank you for wonderfully clear instructions!  I'm afraid that the situation is unchanged, even after choosing `knitr` and linking MiKTeX to R.

Comment: @ arr I am sorry that didn't work for you. Do you have the `rmarkdown` and `knitr` packages installed and loaded? Failing that the only other thing I can suggest is rolling back to `R-3.3.1` which I am using and everything works fine.