# how can i solve this problem when i convert it into PDF document

Tags: r

i just click the knit and then it shows:

```
Error in system(paste(shQuote(path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) : 
  'CreateProcess'调用'C:\PROGRA~2\Pandoc\pandoc.exe --version'失败
Calls: <Anonymous> ... get_pandoc_version -> with_pandoc_safe_environment -> force -> system
停止执行
```

what should i do for solve this problem

Comment: I suspect there's a problem with your pandoc installation. I'd try running getting the pandoc version using the command which gave the error in your own terminal to see if it gives a more meaningful error message. You probably also want to reinstall pandoc. If that doesn't work, this seems like the same error as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713270/rmd-file-not-knitting-in-r-studio-createprocess-failed-to-run?rq=2). Have you tried the suggestion there?